# When search by exclude tag paging is not working

Tags: support, bug, search

When I search for `-[jmeter]`, I find a question about `jmeter` without the `jmeter` tag.

When I click on a different page (2,..) the search results contain the `jmeter` tags.

This is what the search filters show on page one:

[image]

And this is what they show on page 2:

[image]

It works if I change the URL manually from

https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%22-%5bjmeter%5d%22

to

https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&q=-%5Bjmeter%5D

Comment: This also happens when you click the search button again on the first page, seems like the `"` quotes are messing with things