# Can I get more than 50 results per page

Tags: support, search

Can I get more than 50 results per page?

Because of different issue I can't do paging, can I increase number of results in hacky way? 
[when search by exclude tag paging is not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352487/when-search-by-exclude-tag-paging-is-not-working)

Comment: just curious.. cant you use browser extensions or userscripts which retrieve next page on scrolling?

Comment: Found this for FF: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/pagezipper/